# best way to upload a binary file from unreal engine to firebase cloud storage, using blueprints?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

in my VR 'experience', player records an answer to a question in voice. how to upload that file to cloud storage so other players can hear it? i am using unreal engine 4 blueprints.

Answer (score 0):

i started with the firebase plugins (usd 50 and usd 75). the usd 50 one cloud storage node crashes UE frequently, and 100% when packaging for windows (oculus rift, or oculus quest air linked). the usd 75 one cloud storage does not work when packaged for windows. the solution that worked for me were the following two plugins:
.. Low Entry File Manager plugin (usd 40) to convert binary file to byte array
.. VaRest (free) to upload binary file to firebase cloud storage

blueprint pasted below.

please add your answer if there is a better way to do this.

[image]